# Mean of classes by groups of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe including a class `iv` that holds sequences `A` and `B` with different features (`score1` and `score2`). I would like to obtain a dataframe with the mean of each of the features.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'league': ['iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv'],
                   'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'score1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'score2': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]})
```

[image]

So for `score1`, the mean of `A` and `B` (being sequences of different length), would be `[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2]` and for `score2`, it would be `[3, 3, 3, 4]`.

The result I would like to obtain would need to be including also the column `league`, as in the real case I have more than one `league` class (e.g. `iv`, `v`, etc).

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'league': ['iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv'] , 
                   'score1_grouped_mean': [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2],
                   'score2_grouped_mean': [3, 3, 3, 4]})
```

[image]

So, in the end, I only keep `league` and the mean of the `score*` columns.

Comment: Is the expected output exact? Can you explain the calculations?

Comment: thanks, @mozway, just edited it with more information.

Comment: how are you obtaining those mean values, what are they the mean of exactly?

Comment: `score1_grouped_mean` and `score2_grouped_mean` are the mean between `A` and `B` per `score1` and `score2` columns respectively. So first would be obtaining the mean between `A` and `B` I think.

Comment: @Noque, what's the point of keeping *duplicates* in your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks, they are not duplicates, but the mean of A and B. A and B are sequences of different length included in this dataframe, and what I want is the results of the mean of A and B based on longest length sequence (in this case B). As A doesn't contain 4 values, but 3, the last value is a 2 and 4.

Comment: No, actually there are duplicates (*index 1 and 2*) in `df_result`. So, either your question lacks logic/sense, or you failed to clearly express your need.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding with the index, I should have not pasted the image including it. I will try to clarify editing the question more clearly.

Comment: `So for score1, the mean of A and B (being sequences of different length), would be [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2]` To break this down a little more, are you saying that the data `[1, 1, 1]` gets averaged with `[2, 2, 2, 2]`, and the index within the group is what matters for what number gets averaged with what?

Comment: @NickODell, Yes, the index relative to the different  `teams` within each `league`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.groupby(['league', 'team']).cumcount()` to get a column representing index within a group, and use a second groupby to average all scores within the same league and index.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'league': ['iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv', 'iv'],
                   'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'score1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'score2': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]})
df['ts'] = df.groupby(['league', 'team']).cumcount()
df = df.groupby(['league', 'ts'])[['score1', 'score2']].mean().reset_index()
df = df.drop(columns=['ts'])
```

Output:

```
  league  score1  score2
0     iv     1.5     3.0
1     iv     1.5     3.0
2     iv     1.5     3.0
3     iv     2.0     4.0
```